# Need help to get this code to console application

Tags: javascript, cmd, console-application

I have a JavaScript code that I need to get into console application. The script works fine trough cmd but I want to make a console application out of it so its more user friendly. Can someone explain to me how I can write this code in console application or attach it inside the console application with links. I am new to console application so I apologize if I ask anything stupid :-)

When I use it trough cmd then I do the following;
- Run cmd.
- Type "cd downloads" and press enter.
- Type "cscript /nologo process.js log.txt 100 200" and press enter.
- Then I will get a list in the cmd window and I need to have process.js and log.txt in the download folder to make this work.

```js
if(WScript.Arguments.Count() < 3)
{
    WScript.Echo("Usage: cscript process.js <filename> <lower_value> <upper_value>");
    WScript.Quit();
}
 
var filename = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var lowerBound = parseInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(1));
var upperBound = parseInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(2));
 
WScript.Echo("Here is the data from the file associated with the text 'verdi', where the");
WScript.Echo("number following 'verdi' is above " + lowerBound + " and below " + upperBound);
 
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
var file = fso.OpenTextFile("log.txt", 1, false);
 
var lines = file.ReadAll().split('\r');
 
var failed = 0;
for(var idx in lines)
{
    try
    {
        if(lines[idx].indexOf('verdi') > 0)
        {
            var tmp = lines[idx];
            var regex = /verdi\s*\=\s*(\d+)/;
            var result = regex.exec(tmp);
            var num = parseInt(result[1]);
            if(num >= lowerBound && num <= upperBound)
            {
                WScript.Echo(num);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        failed++;
    }
}
 
if(failed > 0)
{
    WScript.Echo("WARNING: one or more lines could not be processed!");
}
```

I have made this code in console application but it doesent work properly. I can choose the values and get the cmd to run. But I don't get the results in the window and print the result to a document.

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object cmd;
        private static int verdi;
        private static int s;
        private static int d;

        public static object WScript { get; private set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Choose lower and upper value
            Console.WriteLine("Choose a lower and upper value:");
            string value = Console.ReadLine();


            //Choose file
            Console.WriteLine("Choose a file to scan:");
            string file = Console.ReadLine();


            //Run the javascript code        
            Console.WriteLine("cd downloads");
            Console.WriteLine("cscript /nologo process.js {0} {1} > mydata.txt", file, value);
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start scan");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C" + command);


            //Quit Console Application
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
                      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` only prints strings. It doesn't allow you to execute commands.
You could try this instead:

```
string command = $"cscript /nologo c:/downloads/process.js c:/downloads/{file} {lowerValue} {upperValue} > mydata.txt");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start($"cmd.exe /C {command}");
```

There is also an error in `process.js`. That script always reads from `log.txt` and ignores the filename.

But why are you using two programs here? You could just have all the code in one file. And why use JavaScript for one and C# for the other?

Comment: Thanks for quick help. I will try the code. Yes I agree with you. There is no reason, I am just new to this. Could I do everything in C#? and what does it take to do it? And again thank you.

Comment: You should be able to translate the js code to C#. Just look at the documentation for the File class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for all help. Now I am almost done. I have made almost everything to C# now. I only need help with a little thing. I can't get the upper and lower value to work. When I load a text file into the RichTextBox then I only want the software to load specific text that are within two given values. Ex; Lower value = "verdi23" and upper value = "verdi30". Then if the text file contains verdi24, verdi 27 and verdi 40 then only verdi24 and verdi27 shall be loaded into the RichTextBox.

Does someone have a solution for loading text when clicking button1 with OpenFileDialog?

Comment: You could use regular expressions just like in your js code. There are many tutorials for this. e.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm